# Help identifying window frame with hinge pin holes

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify this piece (picture below)?

It looks like the top half of a window frame with some 2 pin holes in it.

The size is 1 x 6 x 4, it has no model number on it but does have LEGO branding on the studs.

[image]

Comment: It looks _so_ familiar. I'm wondering if it's not a sub-assembly of a larger part. Couldn't find a good candidate when I went looking through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [821 Garage Door Frame (Old style)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=821).

As the name implies, it was for the old garage door in [these sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=821&in=S) from the 50s and 60s.